# extract string from binary file - regex issue

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed, bsd

I have a binary file that contains a readable filename* bounded by 'namexx:' and 'xx:piece', where x is any digit from 0-9 in both cases.

I am working on a Mac in bash 5.

I have tried using sed:

```sh
cat filename.xxx | sed -E 's/^.*name[0-9]{2}:(.*)[0-9]{2}:piece.*$/\1/'
```

The problem is that the regex does not consume the whole file, so I get a lot of random stuff returned in addition to the captured filename.

I've tried prefixing sed with `LC_ALL=C` as I read in another answer that this will treat all binary data as 'consumable' with wildcards, but it makes no difference (and I may have misunderstood).

I have also tried removing the beginning and end anchors, but that makes no difference either.

---

*The file is a torrent file from which I just want to extract the filename. I *have* looked at bencoding and trying to extract the filename, but it seemed too complex for a trivial task.

Comment: Maybe all you need is `sed -n -E 's/^.*name[0-9]{2}:(.*)[0-9]{2}:piece.*$/\1/p;'`?

Comment: Try `grep -m 1 -o 'name[0-9]\{2\}:\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\}:piece' filename.xxx | sed 's/^name[0-9]\{2\}://' | sed 's/[0-9]\{2\}:piece$//'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -n -E 's/^.*name[0-9]{2}:(.*)[0-9]{2}:piece.*$/\1/p;' filename.xxx
```

Here, `-n` prevents line from being printed and `p` prints the matches (what remains after replacement).

As an alternative, you may use something like

```
grep -m 1 -o 'name[0-9]\{2\}:\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\}:piece' filename.xxx | \
   sed -E 's/^name[0-9]{2}:(.*)[0-9]{2}:piece$/\1/'
```

The first `grep` will only extract the first (`-m 1`) match and then `sed` will only keep the capturing group value inside the result.